# Mapping of elements notation - Cohn - Classic Algebra Page 13

Tags: notation, permutations, function-and-relation-composition

So Cohn uses the notation that many have wanted to change to, being $xfg$ rather than $g(f(x))$, and I have had the example:

> Let $f,g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, be given by $xf = x + 1,xg=x^2$, then $xfg = (x+1)^2 , xgf=x^2+1$

We can clearly see that $x$ gets put into $f$ which all gets put into $g$ for $xfg$

$xf=x+1,(xf)g=xfg=(x+1)g=(x+1)^2$

But after this we do mappings and are told: (For $S=\{1,2,3\}$)

$f=\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3\\2&3&1 \end{pmatrix},g=\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3\\1&3&2 \end{pmatrix}$ which would make me think that $fg=\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3\\2&1&3 \end{pmatrix}$

But instead $fg=\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&3\\3&2&1 \end{pmatrix}$ which is what I would expect $gf$ to equal and $gf$ equals what I would expect $fg$ to equal.

> Why are we doing $xfg$ from left to right, but mapping permutation matrices from right to left?

Comment: $1f=2$, $2g=3$ so $1fg=3$?

Comment: @MarkBennet Oh sorry it was my misunderstanding of course. Yes I see

Comment: @MarkBennet My misunderstanding was that $1,2,3$ get changed to $2,3,1$ meaning one shift to the left(with looping), then the second two elements get inversed by $g$, so $2,3,1$ goes to $2,1,3$

Comment: @MarkBennet Is it coincidence that my method gave me the reversed orders answer? Or does my method somehow actually compute things in the opposite order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misunderstood how permutations work:

If we have the following, from the set $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$

$f=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\3&4&1&2\end{pmatrix}, g= \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\2&1&3&4\end{pmatrix}$

Then
$fg=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4\\3&4&2&1\end{pmatrix}$, since we take the elements and permute them as follows:$$(1\to3\to3)(2\to4\to4)(3\to1\to2)(4\to2\to1)$$

Hence **yes**, it is consistent notation, meaning it does work from left to right.